# unit testing web api

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

We currently have a Web API (.Net core 2.1), it has a service injected which it calls.  the service is based on an interface, the service methods do the business logic and CRUD work.

We are using Entity Framework to talk to the db, using UnitOfWork pattern which the Services are using in their methods.  How do we test these calls, without hitting the db?  I see the Moq framework, but i'm not sure how does it avoid the db calls?  In order to create my controller i need to pass my service, whose constructor takes the unitofwork, done via .net dependency injection.

I'm not sure how to simulate the data portion.  Will Moq automatically do that, or do I need to setup fake data and then Moq will use that for my db calls?  for example if I want to check if a GET request returns data.  or a post returns Ok.

Comment: I see no point in unit testing data access code. You should unit test business logic. Purists out there will probably disagree, but I think its a waste of time. If you do want to unit test data access code and if you are using EF core, then you can use the in-memory feature to make it easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: I agree with William on testing the business logic. but you need to test your db hits if you have logic in your service methods anyhow. Even though, do not mix unit testing with integration testing. You need to mock everything outside of the target class of your test class. So mock everything related to other layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dependency injection, you would mock the object that you are injecting, and you mock that with the help of Moq (I assume you are injecting the one that actually connects to the db).

Basically, You tell Moq how a method should be invoked (you set it up) and what should it return. Then when your business logic tries to use this method from this mocked object, is actually your mocked object answering the call and not the db.

This is a good quick example on how you should use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

But again, I am assuming you are injecting the object that actually makes the call. I think all the objects you inject need to be mocked, since you are testing the object receiving the injections and not the injected ones...

For Moq to be actually helpful, make sure that everything that is a external dependency has its own class and you are injecting it, just so you make your code easily testable.